# What are all of the Evil spells?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I am currently creating an endgame *Pathfinder* Lich, and creating its prepared spells. One of its abilities, granted by the [Maleficium](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/damnation-feats/maleficium-damnation) Feat, increases the save DC of Evil spells by 4 as well as decreasing the level advencement of metamagic feats by 1 (min of +1).

However, on the D20 site, the Paizo site and even in the RULE BOOKS, they don't have any options to search for spells by alignment (or site specific pages in the case of the books). So, **what is the full list of *Pathfinder* evil spells?** Hopefully, other than sitting down and clicking through every spell in the full list?

Comment: Aren't list questions also not acceptable?

Comment: If your table allows some 3.5 material, check out the Aligned Spellcaster Wizard ACF, which can make all non-Good spells Evil

Comment: @YogoZuno The terminology is confusing, but this is not a [list question](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/what-are-list-questions). List questions generate an unbounded list of answers, all equally valid ("What is your favorite RPG?"). A question which asks for a *completable* list as a singular answer is not a "list question" in the sense used on meta.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Archives of Nethys has a [Custom Spell Search](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellsCustom.aspx), that lets you filter by a number of criteria. One of those is *Descriptor*, which is where the Evil tag can be found.

Results of that search give us the following list:

```
Advanced Scurvy: Force the target to contract an advanced form of scurvy.
Agonize: Pain encourages an outsider to obey you.
Animate Dead: Creates undead skeletons and zombies.
Animate Dead, Lesser: Create one skeleton or zombie.
Appearance of Life: Undead appear to be alive
Aura of Cannibalism: Sap the strength of those around you.
Barghest Feast: Absorb power by devouring a humanoid corpse.
Blade of Dark Triumph: Bonded weapon gains ghost touch.
Blasphemy: Kills, paralyzes, weakens, or dazes nonevil subjects.
Blood Ties: When a target is harmed, so is the target's relative.
Blood Transcription: Learn a spell from the target's blood.
Borrow Corruption: Temporarily gain the effects of a corrupted creature's manifestations
Canopic Conversion: Eviscerate a target, creating an advanced mummy from its life essence.
Charnel House: Create an area of semi-real gore
Cloak of Shadows: Shadows protect you from bright light and grants defensive abilities
Contagion: Infects subject with chosen disease.
Contagion, Greater: Infect a subject with a magical disease.
Corruption Resistance: Protects creature against damage from alignment-based attacks.
Create Greater Undead: Create shadows, wraiths, spectres, or devourers.
Create Soul Gem: Draw a recently dead creature's soul into a gem.
Create Undead: Create ghasts, ghouls, mohrgs, or mummies.
Create Variant Mummy: Create a bog mummy, ice mummy, or Osirian tomb guardian.
Cruel Jaunt: Sense creatures suffering from fear, then teleport close to them.
Curse Terrain: Curse an area with four hazards
Curse Terrain, Greater: Curse an area with six dangerous hazards
Curse Terrain, Lesser: Curse an area with three mild hazards
Curse Terrain, Supreme: Curse an area with seven deadly hazards
Curse Water: Makes unholy water.
Cursed Earth: Plants die, living creatures catch diseases, or dead creatures rise as zombies.
Death Candle: Create a howling fire elemental from the remains of the target’s life energy.
Death Clutch: Rip out someone's heart
Death Knell: Kills dying creature; you gain 1d8 temporary hp, +2 to Str, and +1 caster level.
Death Knell Aura: Create an aura that feeds on the souls of those who die within it.
Death Knell Aura, Greater: As death knell aura, except dying creatures die much faster within the aura.
Defile Armor: As sanctify armor, but gain DR 5/good when using judgment or smite.
Demon Dream: Target enemies as nightmare or fellow worshipers of Lamashtu as dream
Desecrate: Fills area with negative energy, making undead stronger.
Dispel Good: +4 bonus against attacks.
Divine Vessel: Change into a huge, otherworldly creature.
Dread Bolt: Harm and possibly sicken good creatures.
Eldritch Fever: Target gains the eldritch ague spellblight.
Enemy's Heart: Absorb an enemy’s power by eating it’s heart.
Epidemic: Infect a subject with a highly contagious disease.
Excruciating Deformation: Target takes Dex and Con damage.
Expel Blood: Rip out the targets blood, forming it into a fiendish water elemental with blood drain
False Resurrection: Appear to resurrect someone but instead allow a shadow demon to possess the corpse.
False Resurrection, Greater: Appear to use true resurrection on someone but instead allow a belier devil to possess the corpse.
Flesh Puppet: Control a zombie in human guise.
Flesh Puppet Horde: Control multiple zombies in human guise.
Flesh Wall: Create a wall of zombies
Fleshworm Infestation: Worms deal hp and Dex damage.
Follow Aura: Gain ability to follow the trail of the aura of an alignment.
Genius Avaricious: Channel the power of Mammon into a single coin.
Ghoul Hunger: Awaken an unnatural hunger in the target, causing it to seek out humanoid flesh.
Grasping Corpse: Cause a corpse to grab or trip a foe
Hellfire Ray: Damn creatures to Hell with a blast of pure hellfire.
Hunger for Flesh: Give a creature a bite attack and a hunger for its own kind's flesh.
Hunger for Flesh, Mass: Give creatures bite attacks and a hunger for their own kind's flesh.
Infernal Healing: Give someone fast healing 1 for a minute, at the cost of a temporary evil alignment.
Infernal Healing, Greater: As infernal healing, except using fast healing 4.
Infuse Decay: Imbue a corporeal undead's natural attacks with dangerous spells
Interrogation: Target answers questions or suffers pain.
Interrogation, Greater: As interrogation, except with more pain and more questions.
Khain's Army: Create a small squad of ghouls led by a ghast, charged with necromantic energy.
Ki Leech: Add to your ki pool when you critically hit.
Lash of the Astradaemon: Enhance your hands into fearsome claws that inflict negative levels.
Magic Circle against Good: As protection spells, but 10-ft. radius and 10 min./level.
Malediction: Banish a soul to Hell if it dies within the next minute.
Malediction (Hero Points): Curse a dying creature to finish it off and gain hero points from its life force.
Masochistic Shadow: Animate a target’s shadow, making it hunger for it’s owner’s life energy.
Maze of Madness and Suffering: Send a target into a dangerous extradimensional maze.
Night Terrors: Disturb a creature's rest with dark dreams
Pain Strike: Inflicts 1d6 nonlethal damage 1 round/level.
Pain Strike, Mass: As pain strike, but affects multiple creatures.
Parasitic Soul: Force a trapped soul into a new body.
Plague Bearer: Make the target a carrier of numerous diseases.
Plague Carrier: Target's attacks carry filth fever.
Plague Storm: Cloud infects creatures like contagion.
Plundered Power: Kill a creature and steal its strongest spell-like ability
Profane Nimbus: Unholy energy damages good creatures that attack you and protects you from good attacks.
Project Weakness: Curse the target with the weaknesses of your vampirism.
Protection from Good: +2 to AC and saves, plus additional protection against selected alignment.
Protection from Good, Communal: As protection from good, but you may divide the duration among creatures touched.
Reaper's Coterie: Target weapon gains bonus damage for defeating enemies.
Retribution: Recent attacker is afflicted with penalties.
Rift of Ruin: Create a rift filled with demons that extends into the Abyss.
Scourge of the Horsemen: Blast an area with soul-rending energy, dealing 1d4 negative levels and 1d6 acid/level.
Screaming Flames: Send forth a wave a flames screaming with the agony of the damned
Sentry Skull: Create a grisly sentinel from the severed head of a humanoid or monstrous humanoid.
Shadow of Doubt: Create a shadowy aura of doubt fueled by a foe’s own inner flaws.
Shadow Projection: Temporarily become a shadow.
Shared Sacrifice: Create a link to the target and direct pain and damage through it.
Shared Suffering: Deal damage to another creature by harming yourself.
Signifer's Rally: Teleport allies to your location.
Slough: Slough off a target's skin.
Spawn Calling: Call the Spawn of Rovagug.
Summon Accuser: Summon an accuser devil to do your bidding.
Summon Barghest I: Summon a barghest to serve you
Summon Cacodaemon: Summon a cacodaemon.
Summon Cacodaemon, Greater: Summon 1d4+1 cacodaemons.
Summon Ceustodaemon: Summon a ceustodaemon.
Summon Derghodaemon: Summon a derghodaemon.
Summon Erodaemon: Summon an erodaemon.
Summon Greater Demon: As summon monster, except to summon a coloxus, omox demon, or 1d3 kalavakus demons.
Summon Infernal Host: Summon host devils.
Summon Lesser Demon: As summon monster, except to summon a brimorak, incubus, thoxel demon, 1d3 schir demons, or 1d4+1 vermlek demons.
Summon Meladaemon: Summon a meladaemon.
Summon Thanadaemon: Summon a thanadaemon.
Symbol of Exsanguination: Triggered rune causes nearby creatures to bleed.
Symbol of Pain: Triggered rune wracks nearby creatures with pain.
Sympathetic Wounds: Force half of the damage you take onto another creature.
Teratoid Caress: Imbue a creature with disfiguring abyssal energy, harming them when they use celestial or healing magic
Tomb Legion: Summon 1d4+2 advanced mummies.
Torpid Reanimation: Animate dead when a specific trigger condition occurs.
Transplant Visage: Remove the face and eyes of a creature, magically melding them with your own.
Undine's Curse: The target loses it’s body’s natural ability to breathe automatically.
Unhallow: Designates location as unholy.
Unhallowed Blows: One natural weapon or unarmed strike of subject undead gets +1 on attack and damage rolls
Unhallowed Blows, Greater: As per unhallowed blows, but a +1 bonus per 4 caster levels
Unholy Aura: +4 to AC, +4 resistance, and SR 25 against good spells.
Unholy Blight: Harms and sickens good creatures (1d8 damage/2 levels).
Unholy Ice: Create wall or javelins of frozen unholy water.
Unholy Ice Weapon: Create a masterwork weapon made of frozen unholy water.
Unholy Sword: Weapon becomes +5, deals +2d6 damage vs. good.
Unholy Ward: Resist damage from holy sources, smite evil, etc.
Vampiric Hunger: Grant a target the fangs and hunger of a vampire.
Vermicious Assumption: Call upon a vermlek demon to invade and inhabit the body of a nearby corpse.
Vile Dog Transformation: Transform ordinary dogs into fiendish minions.
Virulence: Quickly advance the spread of diseases within the targeted creatures.
Vision of Hell: Illusory hellscape makes creatures shaken.
Vision of Lamashtu: As nightmare, but can deliver a second spell when the target awakens.
What Grows Within: Infect others with Xhamen-Dor’s seeded infestation.
Wracking Ray: Fire a ray to deal Dexterity and Strength damage.
```